# Does a damage boosted Moira get more healing reserves?

Tags: overwatch

Moira's rightclick allows her to steal health from enemies and replenish her healing "ammo" for use on her own teammates. My question is, does she get more healing "ammo" when she's damage boosted, or does it stay the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The amount of healing resource recovered by Moira's drain attack is always the same, and independent of how much damage she deals.

If Moira is attacking a hero, not a barrier, she'll recover enough resource to heal for as long as she has drained the enemy: for example, attacking for 2 seconds will grant 2 seconds worth of healing spray.